# How to remove unwanted commas from a string?

Tags: php

How can i remove duplicate commas used in string.

String = ",a,b,c,,,d,,"

I tried rtrim and itrim functions and removed the unwanted commas from beginning and ending .How can i remove duplicate commas ?

Comment: This can be solved using regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: How about iterating over string and copying non-comma chars to another string?

Comment: Thing is if you get string like that then you have an issue on the other side of the stick myfriend. check that side first. if that continues, you either can use `preg_match` function or write function of your own that goes through string char by char and remove a comma if before was a comma spotted.

Comment: Are you still having problems with spaces?

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you might want to accept the answer that most helped you.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/,{2,}/', ',', trim($str, ','));
```

The [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove starting and trailing commas, while the [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will remove duplicate ones.

[See it in action!](http://ideone.com/52NoE6)

Also, as @Spudley suggested, the regex `/,{2,}/` could be replaced with `/,,+/` and it would work too.

EDIT:

If there are spaces between commas, you may try adding the following line after the one above:

```
$str = implode(',', array_map('trim', explode(',', $str)))
```

Comment: @Robert but you would need to now the exact number of duplicates, wouldn't you?

Comment: +1, although I think I'd have just done `,,+` instead of `,{2,}`.

Comment: Yep, your solution is ok ;)

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - yes it could, but it will perform better with two commas, otherwise it's doing unnecessary replacements of a single comma for a single comma.

Comment: @Spudley that is also true, I inserted your version too

Comment: Sorry to say that it won't work for me because their may be a " " (whitespace) between  two commas :'( .. please help..

Comment: @RahulR in your case, after `$str = preg_replace('/,{2,}/', ',', trim($str, ','));`, try doing `$str = implode(',', array_map('trim', explode(',', $str)))`

Answer (score 4):

i think you can just explode your string and then create a new one getting only relevant data

```
$string = ",a,b,c,,,d,,";
$str = explode(",", $string);
$string_new = '';
foreach($str as $data)
{
    if(!empty($data))
    {
        $string_new .= $data. ',';
    }
}
echo substr_replace($string_new, '', -1);
```

This will output

```
a,b,c,d
```

#### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/nQqpWG)

EDITED

If you are having problems with blank spaces you can try use this code

```
$string = ",a,b,c, ,,d,,";

$str = explode(",", str_replace(' ', '', $string));
$string_new = '';
foreach($str as $data)
{
    if(!empty($data))
    {
        $string_new .= $data. ',';
    }
}
echo substr_replace($string_new, '', -1);
```

This should solve spaces issue

Answer (score 2):

Probably not very fast, but a simple method may be:

```
$str = "a,b,c,,,d";
$str2 = "";
while($str <> $str2) {
    $str2 = $str;
    $str = str_replace(',,', ',', $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = ",a,b,c,,,d,,"
echo $str=str_replace(',,','',$str);
?>
```

**Output:**
,a,b,c,d

---

```
<?php 
$str = ",a,b,c,,,d,,"
echo $str=trim(str_replace(',,','',$str),',');
?>
```

**Output:**
a,b,c,d